# How to get the second argument of a type object

Tags: haskell

I have a object form this typedef.

```
type ListDA = (State, [((State, Char), State)], [State])
```

For a Function, i need the second argument and i don't now how i get this.

Comment: a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13472606/how-can-i-call-a-function-that-is-integrated-in-a-type-in-haskell (from the same coursework apparently).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could write a helper function:

```
snd3 :: (a, b, c) -> b
snd3 (_, b, _) = b
```

Or you could do the pattern matching directly in your function parameters, e.g. by replacing

```
yourFunction object = ...
```

with

```
yourFunction object @ (_, secondArgument, _) = ...
```

You may be better off defining a separate type:

```
data ListDA = ListDA {firstField  :: State,
                      secondField :: [((State, Char), State)],
                      thirdField  :: [State]}
```

This method defines accessor functions for you.